# Can I limit a process to a certain amount of time / CPU cycles?

Tags: process, limit

We have a script which runs on our web servers, triggered by customer action, which initiates a unix process to generate some cache files. Because this process acts upon files supplied by our customer, it sometimes misbehaves, running so long that the PHP process which spawns it times out or using so much CPU time that a sysadmin will kill it.

Is there any command which I could run which would limit the CPU time / runtime of the process? I am looking for a command like `/usr/bin/time`, where I could run that command and pass it the commandline I want it to run and limit.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In addition to Gilles answer there is [cpulimit](http://cpulimit.sourceforge.net/) tool that does exactly what you want - including modifing in runtime. Additionally it can limit to only certain CPUs/Cores IIRC.

Answer (score 12):

From within a program, call `setrlimit(RLIMIT_CPU, ...)`. From the shell, call `ulimit -t 42` (this is not standard but supported by most shells (including bash and ksh) on most unix variants). This causes the current process to be killed once it has used up N seconds of CPU time. The limitation is inherited by child processes. A common shell idiom is `(ulimit -t 42; runaway_process)` if you want to be able to run other unlimited processes afterwards from the same shell.

See also [Is there a way to limit the amount of memory a particular process can use in Unix?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/1424/885)
. The principle is the same, you're just limiting a different resource.

Comment: The problem is, I don't have the source code for the program so I can't add `setrlimit` and I'm spawning it through PHP so I don't have a shell...

Comment: @Josh: If you're looking for a construct analogous to `time php /cgi/foo.php`, you can use `bash -c 'ulimit -t 42; exec "$0" "$@"' php /cgi/foo.php`.

Comment: @Josh apache? also I think this stuff can be set system wide...

Comment: @xenoterracide yes it's Apache, but I only want to limit this one process, not all apache processes. Gilles' bash oneliner may work great!

Answer (score 3):

You can also use the `timeout` command to block a process from running for longer than a specified amount of time.

#### example

```
$ date
Mon May  6 07:35:07 EDT 2013
$ timeout 5 sleep 100
$ date
Mon May  6 07:35:14 EDT 2013
```

See the [timeout man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/timeout.1.html) for further details.