# Execute command for x seconds?

Tags: timeout

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Run a command for a specified time and then abort if time exceeds](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/23145/run-a-command-for-a-specified-time-and-then-abort-if-time-exceeds)

Is there a command which allows me to execute another command for at most x seconds?

Imagined example: `runonlyxseconds -s 5 <the real command and its args>`

After that it would be forcefully terminated (e.g. first sending `SIGTERM` and if it doesn't work, `SIGKILL`).

thx

Comment: Wall clock time or CPU time? If it's CPU time, see [Can I limit a process to a certain amount of time / CPU cycles?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/4665)

Comment: [BashFAQ/068](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/068)

Comment: Oh, and if it's wall clock time, see [Run a command for a specified time and then abort if time exceeds](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/23145/run-a-command-for-a-specified-time-and-then-abort-if-time-exceeds)

Comment: er, why not just use the "timeout" command ?

Comment: @Sirex: O_O. Seems I tried this on a Debian installation having no `coretuils` package. Thx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A pure `bash` solution using only near-universally available system commands:

```sh
timeout() {
    if (( $# < 3 )); then
        printf '%s\n' 'Usage: timeout sigterm-seconds sigkill-seconds command [arg ...]'
        return 1
    fi

    "${@:3}" &
    pid=$!

    sleep "$1"

    if ps "${pid}" >/dev/null 2>&1; then
        kill -TERM "${pid}"
        sleep "$2"
        if ! ps "${pid}" >/dev/null 2>&1; then
            printf '%s\n' "Process timed out, and was terminated by SIGTERM."
            return 2
        else
            kill -KILL "${pid}"
            sleep 1
            if ! ps "${pid}" >/dev/null 2>&1; then
                printf '%s\n' "Process timed out, and was terminated by SIGKILL."
                return 3
            else
                printf '%s\n' "Process timed out, but can't be terminated (SIGKILL ineffective)."
                return 4
            fi
        fi
    else
        printf '%s\n' "Process exited gracefully before timeout."
    fi
}
```

Then run as `timeout sigterm-seconds sigkill-seconds command [arg ...]`.